# How to evenly distribute elements to edges of a container?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have a line of elements evenly distributed, with the left and rightmost elements being aligned to their respective edges. This image shows what I currently have with annotations of what's wrong:

[image: This image shows what I currently have with annotations of what's wrong.]

```css
.header-section {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.title {
  font-size: 75pt;
  margin: 0;
}

.subtitles {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}

.subtitles label {
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
  width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-section">
  <h1 class="title">Title goes here</h1>
  <div class="subtitles">
    <label><- this should be left</label>
    <label>This is fine</label>
    <label>this should be right -></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

(the border is just for debugging)

How can I fix this? I assume its something with the justify-content option. Thanks!

Comment: remove flex-grow and width: fit-content which is not needed as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nth-child to specific which label gets specific CSS. So the first one gets aligned to the left, the second gets centered and the third gets text-align right.

```css
.header-section {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.title {
  font-size: 75pt;
  margin: 0;
}

.subtitles {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}

.subtitles label {
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: fit-content;
}

.subtitles label:nth-child(1) {
  text-align: left
}

.subtitles label:nth-child(2) {
  text-align: center
}

.subtitles label:nth-child(3) {
  text-align: right
}
```

```html
<div class="header-section">
  <h1 class="title">Title goes here</h1>
  <div class="subtitles">
    <label>this should be left</label>
    <label>This is fine</label>
    <label>this should be right</label>
  </div>
</div>
```